# How to get all elements between html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all elements from the web page.i used form id or name to get all elements but if there is no form id or name i can't get elements from that page.what is the alternate for this problem. please help.

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? If you have the `document` surely you have all the elements?

Comment: `$("*")` :-D  __________

Comment: @AdamRackis But that assumes jQuery use. Manohar might not be using that. Although, it is the best way to do that :)

Comment: I mean all the objects type and name or value

Comment: @Arindam - I know, hence my smiley face...though from the answers I'm seeing, maybe I should have just put that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery: `$("html *")` which will return all elements between the html tags

for names you must use `$("html *").attr('name')` 
for values `$("html *").val()` or `$("html *").attr('value')`

Comment: Some people get mad at these answers, but sorry, I'd say this is the correct answer, so +1

Comment: can i use this into selenium. Get Eval("j query") because i used java script in the Get Eval method.

Answer (score 6):

You can retrieve an array of all nodes in a html document using `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`. After that you can iterate through that array:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
  //do things with the element, e.g.
  //console.log(allElements[i].type)
  //console.log(allElements[i].id)
  //console.log(allElements[i].innerHTML)
}
```

Update 2014: a more modern approach would be

```
var allEls = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*');
allEls.forEach( function (el) {
      //do things with the element, e.g.
      //console.log(el.type)
      //console.log(el.id)
      //console.log(el.innerHTML)
});
```

Comment: +1 That's how to do it *without* jQuery! Although, it's not exactly correct - it includes the html tag itself. Should be "var all=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByTagName('*')"

Answer (score 0):

Have heard of something called jQuery ? With the help of traversing API you can get to an element you want. Here is the complete list of API - http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery selectors like:  **$("*")** .This particular selector will return all the elements(tags) of that html page.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try this: `document.childNodes`

no framework, lib needed.

Comment: That'll just give you the first level nodes.  What about the divs inside of divs inside of divs.